In profile.ps1 select for pwsh version
I have commands that can only be imported in pwsh vs 7+ and not in 5. Is it is not possible to uninstall ps 5 I like to make the import check for the version and load the proper module.
How would I do that?

“Is it is not possible to uninstall ps 5” - It is impossible to uninstall PowerShell 5.1 it’s also NOT necessary as PowerShell 7 is designed to be installed in a side-by-side configuration with PowerShell 5.1

you can get the Powershell' major version with the following cmlet:
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major

To determine what path to follow in your script depending on the version, do the following:
 
if ( $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 5 )
{

#enter commands for version 5 here

}
elseif ( $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -eq 7 )
{

#enter commands for version 7 here

}

